# How to perform a fuzzy join with fuzzyjoin::difference_* in R

Tags: r, fuzzy-comparison, fuzzyjoin

I'm working with two different datasets that I want to merge based on a threshold. Let's say the two dataframes look like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(lubridate)

df1 = data_frame(Item=1:5, 
                 DateTime=c("2015-01-01 11:12:14", "2015-01-02 09:15:23", 
                            "2015-01-02 15:46:11", "2015-04-19 22:11:33", 
                            "2015-06-10 07:00:00"), 
                 Count=c(1, 6, 11, 15, 9), 
                 Name="Sterling", 
                 Friend=c("Pam", "Cyril", "Cheryl", "Mallory", "Lana"))
df1$DateTime = ymd_hms(df1$DateTime)

df2 = data_frame(Item=21:25, 
                 DateTime=c("2015-01-01 11:12:15", "2015-01-02 19:15:23", 
                            "2015-01-02 15:46:11", "2015-05-19 22:11:33", 
                            "2015-06-10 07:00:02"), 
                 Count=c(3, 7, 11, 15, 8), 
                 Name="Sterling", 
                 Friend=c("Pam", "Kreger", "Woodhouse", "Gillete", "Lana"))
df2$DateTime = ymd_hms(df2$DateTime)
```

What I would like now, is to be able to left join `df2` with `df1` based on a fuzzy match of `DateTime` and `Count` being within two seconds of their respective values, while all other values except `Item` are identical. I thought I could get there with the following:

```
df1 %>%
  difference_left_join(df2, by=c("DateTime", "Count"), max_dist=2)
```

But that gives me the following output:

```
 # A tibble: 8 × 10
  Item.x          DateTime.x Count.x   Name.x Friend.x Item.y          DateTime.y Count.y   Name.y  Friend.y
   <int>              <dttm>   <dbl>    <chr>    <chr>  <int>              <dttm>   <dbl>    <chr>     <chr>
1      1 2015-01-01 11:12:14       1 Sterling      Pam     21 2015-01-01 11:12:15       3 Sterling       Pam
2      1 2015-01-01 11:12:14       1 Sterling      Pam     21 2015-01-01 11:12:15       3 Sterling       Pam
3      2 2015-01-02 09:15:23       6 Sterling    Cyril     NA                <NA>      NA     <NA>      <NA>
4      3 2015-01-02 15:46:11      11 Sterling   Cheryl     23 2015-01-02 15:46:11      11 Sterling Woodhouse
5      3 2015-01-02 15:46:11      11 Sterling   Cheryl     23 2015-01-02 15:46:11      11 Sterling Woodhouse
6      4 2015-04-19 22:11:33      15 Sterling  Mallory     NA                <NA>      NA     <NA>      <NA>
7      5 2015-06-10 07:00:00       9 Sterling     Lana     25 2015-06-10 07:00:02       8 Sterling      Lana
8      5 2015-06-10 07:00:00       9 Sterling     Lana     25 2015-06-10 07:00:02       8 Sterling      Lana
```

This is close, except that row 3 should not have merged given that the names are different (and I would have expected row 2 to merge given the thresholds, even though I don't want it to).

How do I end up with the following dataframe? Note that the second row and third row from `df2` was not merged despite `DateTime` and `Count` meeting the threshold limit. This is because the other columns (except `Item`) were not identical.

```
desired_output
#   Item            DateTime Count     Name  Friend
# 1    3 2015-01-02 15:46:11    11 Sterling  Cheryl
# 2    2 2015-01-02 09:15:23     6 Sterling   Cyril
# 3    5 2015-06-10 07:00:00     9 Sterling    Lana
# 4   25 2015-06-10 07:00:02     8 Sterling    Lana
# 5    4 2015-04-19 22:11:33    15 Sterling Mallory
# 6    1 2015-01-01 11:12:14     1 Sterling     Pam
# 7   21 2015-01-01 11:12:15     3 Sterling     Pam
```

Comment: I think it gives you the error you mentioned if you don't use `lubridate` on the data before the join. Otherwise if gives you a different message. BTW sorry if I'm missing something obvious but where does "Duration" come from?

Comment: Ah, sorry! I'm dummied up the data to mask what it really is, but then kept using real variable names. I'll clean that up.

Comment: Also removed reference to the error given that you pointed out why it happened, and updated with the result of calling that line of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, so, the message you got was because the fuzzy match can't be calculated on a non-numeric column.

The thing to do is to convert it to numeric. Since your caliper is in seconds I converted it to seconds and then made them numeric:

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(lubridate)

df1 = data_frame(Item=1:5, 
                 DateTime=c("2015-01-01 11:12:14", "2015-01-02 09:15:23", 
                            "2015-01-02 15:46:11", "2015-04-19 22:11:33", 
                            "2015-06-10 07:00:00"), 
                 Count=c(1, 6, 11, 15, 9), 
                 Name="Sterling", 
                 Friend=c("Pam", "Cyril", "Cheryl", "Mallory", "Lana"))
df1$DateTime1 = as.numeric(seconds(ymd_hms(df1$DateTime)))

df2 = data_frame(Item=21:25, 
                 DateTime=c("2015-01-01 11:12:15", "2015-01-02 19:25:56", 
                            "2015-01-02 15:46:11", "2015-05-19 22:11:33", 
                            "2015-06-10 07:00:02"), 
                 Count=c(3, 6, 11, 15, 8), 
                 Name="Sterling", 
                 Friend=c("Pam", "Kreger", "Woodhouse", "Gillete", "Lana"))
df2$DateTime1 = as.numeric(seconds(ymd_hms(df2$DateTime)))

df1 %>%
  difference_left_join(y=df2, by=c("DateTime1", "Count"), max_dist=2)
```

based on our discussion in the comments a simple tweak to subset this to the case of other character columns matching would be:

```
df1[df2$Friend == df1$Friend,] %>%
  difference_left_join(y=df2[df2$Friend == df1$Friend,], by=c("DateTime1", "Count"), max_dist=2)
```

That example is just for `Friend` but of course you could use `&` to do it with multiple columns.

Comment: Is it possible to specify that all character variables must match exactly? I suppose it would be easier to just take the output from `difference_left_join` and then filter out the records where, for example, `Name.x != Name.y`.

Comment: @brittenb I thought you only wanted them to match within 2 seconds?

Comment: Admittedly, after re-reading my question and the title, I wasn't very clear. I do want them to match within 2 seconds of each other, but only when every other column (except `Item`) matches.

Comment: @brittenb Oh, ok I see. Yea I can do that as soon as I get a free second.